# Remove Wordpress function in Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have the following function sat in the parent functions.php file:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
# Site Title 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#

function theme_slug_setup() {
   add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup' );

if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) {
    function theme_slug_render_title() { ?>

        <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title> <?php
    }

    add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
}
```

I would like to disable it first of all and then try and replace it in my child functions file...

I have tried this to replace it:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup' );


    function theme_slug_render_title() { ?>

        <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title> <?php
    }

    add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
```

or these to remove it:

```
function child_remove_parent_function() {
    remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup' );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'child_remove_parent_function' );


function child_remove_parent_function2() {
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'child_remove_parent_function2' );
```

But I can't seem o get anything working!! Would someone be able to point out where I'm going wrong?? Thanks!

++++++++++++++ EDIT ++++++++++++++

I've had to add the remove_action code inside another function - This works on its own and removes the title tag...

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_head_title', 0 );

function remove_head_title() {

    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
    remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your child theme function.php file you need

first : remove actions : (you don't need to wrap this line in other actions)

```
remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup' );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
```

after : redeclare new function if necessary :

```
function child_theme_slug_setup() { //Function name must be different of function in parent theme
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_slug_setup' );
```

**EDIT :**
So, the complete code of your function.php child theme must be :

```
remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup' );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );

function child_theme_slug_setup() { //Function name must be different of function in parent theme
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_slug_setup' );
```

Comment: Have a look, so you will more clear on replacing parent function by child function: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/is-it-possible-to-disable-a-function-of-a-parent-theme

Comment: Thanks Fabien - Do the remove_action lines need to be inside their own function? As this isn't working, it doesn't seem to effect anything at all...

Comment: No, `remove_action` function must be directly in your file (not inside an other function). the problem in your initial code is probably because  you call your `remove_action` in an other action (it's too late). Is my edit more clear ?

Comment: Thanks again - But this still hasn't worked, If you look at the edit I've made to the original question, I added it inside another function and it seems to work - I just need to now combine this with the rest of the code to replace the title?

Answer (score 1):

add this below code in child theme function.php file for **title tag**

```
     remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup' );
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );

        function child_theme_slug_setup() { 
            add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
        }
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_slug_setup' );

        if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) {
    function child_theme_slug_render_title() {
?>
<title><?php wp_title( '-', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'child_theme_slug_render_title' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesn't seem to be working - It seems to have no effect whatsoever and the title tags is still there (Even if I replace the wp_title part with my own code or even simple text...

Comment: Also, make sure the following is not in your header.php template:

<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

Comment: Thanks - However, It's still no working, If you look at the edit I've made to the original question, I added it inside another function and it seems to work - I just need to now combine this with the rest of the code to replace the title?

Comment: can you share your credentials? so we will check it.